# Interpretation of results in multilevel logistic regression

Tags: logistic, stata, multilevel-analysis

I estimated a two-level logistic regression model with random intercept and random coefficients.

The dependent variable is if someone participated in a demonstration (1) or not (0).
My independent variables are age, gender, party affilliation (yes/no), political interest (yes/no) etc... Random coefficients are estimated for party affil. and political interest., because I assume (based on theory) that the effects of those factors vary between states, I will have no contextual effects yet in the model.

My respondents are clustered within 16 states (ca. 500-900 respondents per state).

I used Stata (melogit) and found party affiliation and political interest to be significant (positive) predictors of the probability to participate in a demonstration on the individual level. ICC is 9.3 percent.

I tried to interprete this and actually read a lot (including LEMMA) but I feel a bit at loss, because I've never done this before and most books/texts focus on much more advanced things.

My questions are

1) What can I say about individual effects in every state? In general, I found a significant effect over all cases, when the clustering of cases (states) was controlled for. But it is still possible that there are states where the effect may not exist?

2) How can I analyse post-hoc if this effect exists in every country (other than running separate regressions per country).  I predicted random effects per state (predict re*, reffects) that vary substantially, but I don't know how to proceed further.